# Is there any easy way to test the feature High availability in open source JS7?

Tags: scheduler, oracle-ebs

We are on the way of replacing Control M with JS7 scheduler which is an open source for scheduling jobs in our EBS application. How do we test the high availability feature with minimal efforts in this scheduler?

We are on the way of migrating jobs to JS7 in test environment.

Answer (score 0):

The high availability feature of JS7 is only available with the commercial license. If you have a commercial license you should be able to ask the people at JS7.

Comment: We have 1000+ Jobs running every day in our application. Can open source Jobscheduler itself can handle this efficiently? or it is must that we buy license for this sort of scenario to work. Please throw some light on this if you have ever worked with it